# Why stacktrace of valgrind dividied to two parts?

Tags: c, valgrind

In [the docs](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html), explaining Valgrind's Memcheck error reports, there is a such example in section *4.2.1. Illegal read / Illegal write errors*:

```
Invalid read of size 4
   at 0x40F6BBCC: (within /usr/lib/libpng.so.2.1.0.9)
   by 0x40F6B804: (within /usr/lib/libpng.so.2.1.0.9)
   by 0x40B07FF4: read_png_image(QImageIO *) (kernel/qpngio.cpp:326)
   by 0x40AC751B: QImageIO::read() (kernel/qimage.cpp:3621)
 Address 0xBFFFF0E0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or free'd
```

And here is my example:

```
==20285== Invalid read of size 8
==20285==    at 0x401E8C: arraylist_get (arraylist.c:68)
==20285==    by 0x401254: test_arraylist_remove (test_arraylist.c:68)
==20285==    by 0x401366: main (tests.c:31)
==20285==  Address 0x59d65f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==20285==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20285==    by 0x402302: pool_realloc (pool.c:57)
==20285==    by 0x401D97: arraylist_remove (arraylist.c:53)
==20285==    by 0x401243: test_arraylist_remove (test_arraylist.c:67)
==20285==    by 0x401366: main (tests.c:31)
```

Notice - in my case there is a continuation after `Address 0x59d65f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd` - there is another stack trace in this error. What is it mean?

ps
Full Valgrind output:
https://gist.github.com/AndrewPashkin/b1b1b484153642b1ae14

Comment: The first trace is where the invalid read happened; the second part is where the memory being read was originally allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two separate stack traces.

Firstly, a description of the invalid access, with a stack trace of the code at that point:

```
==20285== Invalid read of size 8
==20285==    at 0x401E8C: arraylist_get (arraylist.c:68)
==20285==    by 0x401254: test_arraylist_remove (test_arraylist.c:68)
==20285==    by 0x401366: main (tests.c:31)
```

Secondly, a description of the memory being accessed, with a stack trace of the code that allocated it:

```
==20285==  Address 0x59d65f0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 alloc'd
==20285==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20285==    by 0x402302: pool_realloc (pool.c:57)
==20285==    by 0x401D97: arraylist_remove (arraylist.c:53)
==20285==    by 0x401243: test_arraylist_remove (test_arraylist.c:67)
==20285==    by 0x401366: main (tests.c:31)
```